# Direct selection vs confirmation of selection

Tags: usability, sort

Which is best practice?

A user clicks a SORT button, goes to a screen with a longish list of "sort by" options. e.g. Sort by: date, price etc...

1. The user selects an option and is taken directly back to the screen they were on with the sort option applied ***without having to confirm their selection***. (If they make a mistake they have to click SORT option again to edit their "sort by" selection)
2. The user selects a "sort by" option and then needs to ***press a button first*** to confirm their choice before being taken back to the screen they were on with the sort option applied. (This allows them to choose another option if they accidentally click the wrong sorting option)

Note that the SORT option only rearranges the data on screen and is non-destructive.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @Brad. Please provide some context. Is there any hazard associated with picking the wrong option? Is there a technical constraint that makes it impossible to change the option after it is selected?

Comment: Thanks Graham. No there is no hazard associated with making the wrong choice or any technical constraints. The user simply has to click sort and make another selection. Also thanks to the people who have responded so quickly. This is very helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

I would only ask for confirmation of a selection if it gets the person into a bad state that is hard to get out of or it changes their data in a way that is potentially damaging.

Otherwise, it should be easy for them to try out a lot of different filtering options and not requiring a confirmation is a great way to allow this...

Answer (score 0):

The chance, that your users make the right choice when choosing a sort option is bigger then making the wrong choice (if not, there seems somthing to be wrong with the sortoption dialogue). So why force them to confirm every time, only beacause a few times when they took the wrong option the would have to click SORT again? The design should be made for the "happy flow" an not for the exception.